# Any way to track if the URL was copied?

Tags: javascript, address-bar

Any way to check if the visitor has copied the URL or some of it?

Thanks!

Comment: The url of what exactly? A text on you website, or from the address bar in the browser? If the latter, then no. And no, you cant really tell if someone copys text from your website either. What you can do is put a url in a input text field. Then use javascript/jquery to check if a user presses a button, or in this case, two buttons (ctrl+c) while that text field is in focus. However, those copying by right clicking and presses copy, you wont catch. So either way, you get a half assed code.

Comment: There is one other way tho. Lots of webpages gives you a "Copy this text link". Which is actually a invisible flash file that is positioned over that "Copy this text"-link. So flash allows the user to copy, since browser dont allow you to trigger a copy to the system clipboard. This flash file can propably tell your site that text has been copied if  you have a listener for that. A lot of work though.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll check what we can do with flash.
I want to know if the visitor copied the URL of the current page on my site,
or even if he copied anything at all. Just to better understand the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this directly.

The URL is not a part of your document and you can do nothing with it.
There is an API to work with system clipboard but it is working only within document sandbox (or not working at all until user allows is) according to security policy of a browser.

Preventing copying text is absolutely not efficient way to protect something.
A user can simply retype it or disable this script.
Invent something else like dynamic links, dynamic pages from back-end, one-time authentication etc.

Comment: Thank you!

I actually don't want to prevent them from doing that, but to know if they did.